# replacing missing entires of variable 1 by non-missing values of variable 2 sql in googlebigquery (standard sql)

Tags: sql, replace, null

I am trying to create a new `variable` called STREET NAME which will take a value of ON_STREET_NAME if it is `not null` or OFF_STREET_NAME if ON_STREET NAME `is null`. 
I tried using

```
ifnull(on_street_name, off_street_name)
and
    coalesce(on_street_name, off_street_name)
```

but none seemed to work. Any advice?

[image: The snapshot of the variable and data structure]

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the `on_street_name` column, making it appear that the column is empty?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no such thing as a "variable" in standard SQL). Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Your logic (particularly with `coalesce()`) is correct.  Hence, either your overall query is not correct or the data is not what you think it is.

Comment: There is no whitespace in the on_street_name. It is just missing info which exists in the off_street_name column.

Comment: Do you know another way of doing it? Perhaps joins and subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i was able to experiment different things and found this to work. Having null and empty space works differently. Here is the solution.

```
coalesce(nullif(on_street_name,''),off_street_name) as street_name
```

It works like magic :)